# What is the maximum number of triangles we can draw in a planar graph using at most 30 nodes and 50 edges

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

I'm trying to solve this problem because I need to implement it into my program for calculating some values related to this.

Namely, I need to find what is the maximum number of triangles we can draw if we can use only up to 30 nodes and up to 50 edges. The triangles can share point, points or sides.

I started thinking if we can put one point in the center and then we put all the other points around it and then connect with the point in the center, but it looks like this wont be the maximum number.

Comment: How do you count triangles? Can a triangle have nodes and edges _inside_ it, or must it be a separate face of the graph?

Comment: I assume by the tags that you want your triangles to lie in a plane, so no triangles in 3 dimensions, no triangles on a sphere, etc?

Comment: Furthermore, why don't you get the maximal number by one point in the middle and the rest around it? Can you give an example on how you would construct more than 29 triangles (this is what is possible with one point in the middle) while only having 30 nodes?

Comment: @DirkLiebhold: 17 points on a line, connected by 16 edges, each of these points joined to one common point on the left and one common point on the right: 32 triangular faces with 19 vertices and 50 edges.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ok, that's nice.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I get the same result starting from a triangular lattice (19 points as a size-3 hexagon), joining edges on the outside and then deleting any edge to make 50 edges: 32 triangles.

Comment: @Parcly: In general, if you draw a quadrilateral, put 15 points in _random_ positions inside it, and then add edges _at random_ until all the internal faces are triangles, then due to the Euler characteristic you will _always_ end up with 32 triangles and 50 edges. (But you can get more triangles than that if a "triangle" doesn't need to be a face).

Comment: Every triangle has $3$ edges, and every edge is in at most $2$ triangles, so $3T\leq2E$, where $E$ is the number of edges and $T$ the number of triangles. This means you cannot have more than $33$ triangles given only $50$ edges.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ denote the number of triangles in such a graph, and $E$ the number of edges. Every triangle has precisely $3$ edges, and every edge is adjacent to at most $2$ triangles, so $3T\leq2E$. Given that $E\leq50$ it follows that $T\leq33$.

If $T=33$ then there is precisely one edge $e_0$ that is adjacent to precisely one triangle; every other edge is adjacent to precisely two triangles. But then the face that $e_0$ is adjacent to that is not a triangle has other edges adjacent to it (assuming the graph is simple), contradicting the fact that $e_0$ is the unique edge adjacent to a non-triangle. Hence $T<33$.

Examples of planar graphs with at most $30$ vertices and at most $50$ edges with $32$ triangular faces have already been given, so this is the maximum. The following sequence of planar graph gives another example:

[image]

The sixth graph in this sequence has $18$ vertices, $48$ edges and $32$ faces, all of which are triangular.

---

If the graph is not required to be simple, then the maximum number of triangles is in fact $33$. The following sequence of planar graphs yields an example:

[image]

The $n$-th graph has $V_n=2n+2$ vertices, $E_n=6n+2$ edges and $F_n=4n+2$ faces, of which $T_n=F_n-1=6n+1$ are triangular. So for $n=8$ we get a planar graph on $18$ vertices with $50$ edges and $34$ faces, of which $33$ are triangular. The argument above shows that this is maximal.

Answer (score 0):

I got 50 edges 19 nodes 32 triangles. [image]

Answer (score -1):

Take the complete graph on 10 nodes. It needs ${10 \choose 2}=45$ edges. You get ${10 \choose 3}=120$ triangles. And you have 5 more edges.

Comment: The graph needs to be planar.